# Cannibalism and energy conservation

Tags: energy-conservation, biophysics, biology

[This question in biology forum](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/94152/59521) asks why cannibalism is not an evolutionarily stable situation. In this respect one has to distinguish *occasional* and *exclusive* cannibalism - in the latter case one could argue that the reduction of population due to the cannibalism is always faster than the reproduction rate:
$$
\frac{dN}{dt} = rN - cN,\\
r \leq c.
$$
While it looks self-obvious with the numbers for a typical mammal, such as a lion (which eats at least once a week, but produces only a few units of progeny a year). **Could one make an energy-based argument that would apply to any species (from bacteria to higher organisms)?** In other words, species cannot be sustainable without influx of energy ("calories") from outside - by eating other species, plants, photosynthesis, etc.

**Update**
A couple of clarifications in view of the discussion in the comments:

- From a physicist's viewpoint, live organisms can be though of as *heat engines*, taking energy from the environment (in the form of hydrocarbons, solar radiation, etc.) and using this energy to do useful work (constructing themselves and replicating). So energetic constrains on evolution and dynamics is a natural thing to consider and certainly physics.
- I am looking for a mathematical model, based on energy principles, and showing that in cannibal species the only stable equilibrium is extinction. It is probably similar to Lottka-Volterra equations, but I am looking for solid energetic arguments rather than empirical motivations. I suppose that some real research has been done in this subject, so references to scientific literature would be appreciated.

**Reference**

- Thermodynamics of species is routinely considered in ecology, see, e.g., [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0251):

```
From a thermodynamic point of view, organisms are transduction mechanisms that 
distribute an influx of energy down along the steepest gradients to the ecosystem's 
diverse repositories of chemical energy, i.e., populations of species. Transduction 
machineries, i.e. ecosystems assembled from numerous species, may emerge and evolve 
toward high efficiency on large areas that hold more matter than small ones. 
This results in the well-known logistic-like relationship between the area and the 
number of species. The species-area relationship is understood, in terms of 
thermodynamics, to be the skewed cumulative curve of chemical energy distribution 
that is commonly known as the species-abundance relationship.
```

- A review outlining the use of the thermodynamic laws for studying energy balance and non-equilibrium behavior in ecological systems: [Thermodynamics in Ecology—An Introductory Review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7517404/)

Comment: It is about energy conservation and thermodynamics. But nonlinear dynamics is relevant as well - perhaps an appropriate model exists already.

Comment: So what is your question here?

Comment: @BioPhysicist energy balance equation or something like this, demonstrating that the exclusive cannibalism leads to extinction. A larger energy prospective on prey and predator could be also interesting.

Comment: But what is your question? This post looks more like an open-ended model request.

Comment: @BioPhysicist you want that instead of "I sm wondering..." I write a sentence with a question mark? Is that it?

Comment: Ok, so you really are just asking for someone to construct a model for you?

Comment: @BioPhysicist a well motivated model would qualify as an answer, although references to real research work could be more interesting.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is about biology.

Comment: @FredericThomas Live organisms are heat engins, which take energy from the environment (in a form of sugars), process it to do useful work (like constructing themselves and replicating) and eject teh rest of it into the environment as heat. You are basically saying that statistical/physics and thermodynamics, and energy balance approaches are not physics.

Comment: @FredericThomas PSE is not against biology questions as long as they also are relevant to physics

Answer (score 4):

A simple energy argument shows that exclusive cannibalism is not a viable long term strategy.

All metabolic processes are less than $100\%$ efficient. So each generation loses some of its energy input to the environment as unrecoverable heat energy. In an exclusively cannaballistic species this means that the energy input available to each successive generation is less than the energy available to the previous generation. It is basically the same reason why you cannot survive forever by burning your own body fat.

I suppose it is conceivable that a species could adapt to this shrinking energy budget by having a slower and slower metabolism in each generation, but you would quickly end up with a species that was for all practical purposes indistinguishable from rocks.

Comment: Basically, this is it. I was also thinking about writing a model, something like: every specimen can loses energy  at a constant rate, proportional to its mass (which can be taken equal to the energy) and needs to replenish it at a same rate by eating other specimen. When replicating the total energy is distributed equally among the specimen.

Comment: To quote Dawkins 1976, "Mole rats are homocoprophagous, which is a polite way of saying that they eat one another's faeces (not exclusively: that would run afoul of the laws of the universe)."